# Marvel license issue. Clusters grayed out

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-marvel

I have an Elastic 2.1.0 cluster, logging to an external Marvel 2.1 with Kibana 4.3.1.

All worked fine with trial licenses, but when I updated them with a basic one, all clusters gone grayed out in Kibana and I cannot see info of any of them anymore.

I've tried using the same license on both clusters, with no result. There's nothing relevant in either cluster logs.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you can only monitor one cluster with the Basic license, see the information here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/marvel-2-1-basic-licence-cannot-access-cluster-data/39293.